# React: Passing down props to Component from useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

First, the title might be all together wrong. I am learning JavaScript and React. I started with React a week ago.

I have been trying out different variations of this function for hours. I think I might be reading old practice and getting it confused with new or best practice. At the moment I am getting "**TypeError: Cannot read property 'map" of undefined"**

```
   export default function App() {
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([
    {
      title: "Finish portfolio",
      description: "finish the portfolio",
      isCompleted: false,
      id: shortid.generate(),
    },
    {
      title: "Feed Dog",
      description: "Take out food and fee dog",
      isCompleted: false,
      id: shortid.generate(),
    },
    {
      title: "Finish portfolio",
      description: "Do HTML, CSS and JavaScript",
      isCompleted: false,
      id: shortid.generate(),
    },
  ])

    const [title, setTitle] = useState("")
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("")
    //const [isCompleted, setIsCompleted] = useState("false")

    function handleCompletedTodo (itemId) {
   setTodoList(prevList=> {
     todoList = prevList.todoList.map(todo=> {
      if(todo.id === itemId){
        return {...todo, isCompleted: !todo.isCompleted}
      } return todo
     })
     return {todoList}
   })
 }

// This is what is in my component **************************************

import React from "react";



const TodoItem = (props) => {
  const {title, description, isCompleted, id} = props.todo
  return (
    <li className="todo_item">
      <p>{title}</p>
      <p>{description}</p>
      <input 
      type="checkbox" 
      checked={isCompleted}
      onChange={()=> props.handleComplete(id)} 
      /> 
      </li>
  );
}

export default TodoItem;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code like this.

```
...
setTodoList(prevList => {
    prevList.todoList = prevList.todoList ? prevList.todoList : [] 
    todoList = prevList.todoList.map(todo => {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `prevList` in `setTodoList` is the pr value of `todoList`. So you need to update to:
`prevList.map`